# best PHP programming approach?

Tags: php, javascript, oop, frameworks

i guess that many of us has acceptable years of experience in PHP programming, me myself got 5 years programming in PHP since in University (not very solid), i just want to gather some suggestion here,

- what is better approach in PHP OOP?
- Since there is a lot of PHP framework out there as well as javascript framework, can anyone share their experience in using one of them as well as using both of the PHP and javascript framework together especially for developing enterprise system? (my company want to start using framework, ISP company)
- if someone has his/her own framework or class or php file so on and so forth, mind to share? now I've only database connection class.

I've never use any php framework before, just jquery as javascript framework, my company has a messed up of programming approach because they did not actually a software house, so all the files are scattered across the server, I see that there are some question before about the framework but i just want to know you all approaches on OOP and in developing massive web apps using PHP, or maybe someone kind enough to share their solid written class. Also pro's and con's of all this things. Thanks in advance.

edit:
FYI I'am developing network management system, sometimes deal with perl, linux script, RRD MRTG and all, but my colleague is only 3 of them include my boss, so have to monitor network as well as ad-hoc development, the design and programming approach from past staff is sux all the way...@_@

Comment: sorry for annoying you guys but i didn't get any place to quick answer my question except in such this collaboration website.

Comment: Not to use PHP :) (Ducks as things are thrown at him) :D

Comment: err @andrewWinn, what did you mean actually?

Comment: I think @andrewWinn is one of the "don't you dare using PHP, it is not a programming language and it sucks at whatever it is and does" people that populate internet this days. :)

Comment: In my defense it was a joke . . . I am a fan of the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are so many [Best PHP Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php%20frameworks&tab=votes) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249984/php-framework-decision-analysis-paralysis) already, your answer is bound to be found in one of them.  A lot of these questions are old though, so remember that newer versions of these frameworks might solve older problems.

A quick summary of frameworks I've seen in use (no particular order):

- [Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/)
- [CakePHP](http://www.cakephp.org/)
- [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/)
- [Code Igniter](http://codeigniter.com/)

Other suggestions, using git/svn for source control is a MUST (even if you are the only developer, it can save you a lot of time)

Personally, I use ZF.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, yeah i know that there is an older post about framework, i try to project this from my angel...

Comment: @Nazmin, I personally like CodeIgniter more and I think it's better to start using it if you're a beginner at this stuff.

Answer (score 3):

> all the files are scattered across the server

Learning a version control tool (git, mercurial, bazaar, subversion...) is one of the best things you can invest your time on.

Comment: good suggestion, my boss also thought about this.

Answer (score 2):

[Why use PHP OOP over basic functions and when?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716412/why-use-php-oop-over-basic-functions-and-when)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648/what-php-framework-would-you-choose-for-a-new-application-and-why

etc.

Comment: thanks for the link, one of the link i've already seen before...will review it again and grab something...