# PHP - what is the difference between this function and this class?

Tags: php

I have a php code that is procedural. So I am changing it to object oriented.
I have a function like this:

```
<?php

 function get_username(){
  $user= "maria";
  return $user;
 }

 function get_name(){
  $user= "Maria Campbell";
  return $user;
 }

echo get_username();
echo get_name();

?>
```

and if I convert it to object oriented, it will be like:

```
<?php

class user{

 public function get_username(){
  $user= "maria";
  return $user;
 }

 public function get_name(){
  $user= "Maria Campbell";
  return $user;
 }

}


$userfunctions = new user();

echo $userfunctions->get_username();
echo $userfunctions->get_name();


?>
```

my question is, what I gain doing the second way? it is the same thing, isnt it?

Comment: Actually - you gain nothing, on such simple examples. Object shouldn't be  just a bunch of functions wrapped in class. Keep it procedural, if it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference at first glace, is *nothing*. However, when you start using classes, you can use [inheritance](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php) and other great things, which greatly improves your code and gives you more scope to various techniques, such as;

- Separation of logic
- [Visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)
- Namespaces
- [Interfaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) and [Traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php)
- ... [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716412/why-use-php-oop-over-basic-functions-and-when)
- ... [See the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)

If you wanted a more in depth answer, using a class *has major differences* between your procedural code. **But,** if we take your code literally, there is not enough difference to comment on (apart from 1 being in a class and the other not).